# Iframe transparent background

Tags: iframe, background, transparent

My app has a modal dialog with an iframe inside it. I've written my jQuery code such that when the dialog opens, it sets the appropriate 'src' attribute of the iframe so the content loads up.  However, during the delay between the dialog opening and the content loading, the iframe appears conspicuously as a white box.  I'd prefer the iframe have a transparent background.

I've tried setting allowtransparency="yes" on the iframe. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 63):

I've used this creating an IFrame through Javascript and it worked for me:

```
// IFrame points to the IFrame element, obviously
IFrame.src = 'about: blank';
IFrame.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
IFrame.frameBorder = "0";
IFrame.allowTransparency="true";
```

Not sure if it makes any difference, but I set those properties before adding the IFrame to the DOM.
After adding it to the DOM, I set its src to the real URL.

Comment: +1 : Didn't know about the allowTransparency till now. Thanks :)

Comment: For me the issue was that I defined 
`<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />`
in the header. After removing that, the Sign In With Google button displays in the iFrame nicely (even without allowTransparency=true).

Comment: as mentioned above, the issue for me was the`<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark" />`. [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77604431/6908282) answer for more details

Comment: also looks like `allowTransparency` is not longer supported. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489906/6908282)

Answer (score 43):

```
<style type="text/css">
body {background:none transparent;
}
</style>
```

that might work (if you put in the iframe)
along with

```
<iframe src="stuff.htm" allowtransparency="true">
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the background color of the source page to `none` and allow transparency in the `iframe` element.

Source page (for example, `source.html`):

```
<style type="text/css">
    body
    {
        background:none transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Page with iframe:

```
<iframe src="source.html" allowtransparency="true">Error, iFrame failed to load.</iframe>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just load the frame off screen or hidden and then display it once it has finished loading. You could show a loading icon in its place to begin with to give the user immediate feedback that it's loading.

Comment: Because there is no reliable way to know when the iframe has finished loading. Iframe navigation is done by setting its 'href' attribute, not with remote loading.

Comment: you COULD, if you used setTimeout to trigger visibility after a short period of time ,giving frame time to load.. ... Mayb not a solution, but a possible workaround..

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the iframe's body transparently. It works for me:

```
const iframe = document.createElement( 'iframe' );

iframe.onload = function() {
    const doc = iframe.contentWindow.document,
        head = doc.querySelector( 'head' ),
        style = doc.createElement( 'style' );

        style.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
        style.innerHTML = 'body { background: transparent!important; }';

        head.appendChild( style );
}
```