# Transparent Iframe Body

Tags: css, iframe, background, transparent

I need to have a (crossdomain) iframe with dynamic width and height.

My question is,
Can I create an iframe with 100% size and a transparent background that will show the parent of this iframe, behind it ?

Can I attach a css property or a transparent gif for the iframe background to make that effect ?

Thanks.

Comment: Accept theatomicdude's answer

Answer (score 126):

yes you can (if i understand your question correctly)

heres the code
if you have edit access to the iframe content put this in the head (of the iframe)

```
<style type="text/css">
 <!-- BODY {background:none transparent;}-->
 </style>
```

and then embed the iframe like this

```
<iframe src="frame.htm" allowtransparency="true">
```

Comment: Thanks!, glad I could help but an up vote will  do, too young for beer anyway haha

Comment: One note - the transparent iframe will not pass clicks through to the parent window, so users might get confused by elements on the page that they can see but not click.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that the clicks wouldn't pass through. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @atomthegod but snacks tho

Comment: the given link is broken.

Comment: thanks for this! your answer should get accepted! though this appears to work without `allowtransparency="true"`. Is there a reason you included this part?

Comment: looks like `allowTransparency` is not longer supported. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9489906/6908282)

Answer (score 3):

By inspecting the iframe page you might find out there is color on some parts of the page. My suggestion would be to start from the highest component when adding the transparency:

```css
html {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

And then in the iframe element:

```html
<iframe src="www.." allowtransparency="true">
```

Comment: it seems to work without `allowtransparency="true"`. is there a reason you included this part? thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2):

In modern browsers, the issue is the meta tag for color-scheme (reference: https://fvsch.com/transparent-iframes)

> If the color scheme of an iframe differs from embedding document, iframe gets an opaque canvas background appropriate to its color scheme.

So the way that I fixed this issue was by adding the color-scheme meta in my iframe

```html
<meta name="color-scheme" content="light dark">
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't tested, but iframes (any element) should have a default background of being transparent.

If that's not true, you can set them to being transparent in CSS `background: transparent`

If that doesn't work, you can use CSS opacity filters:
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_image_transparency.asp