# IFrame AllowTransparency attribute ignored

Tags: html, iframe

I am having some problems getting transparency to work when embedding an iframe onto a page. I have set the allowTransparency attribute of the iFrame to true. However once the page is displayed I use internet explorer's F12 Developer Tools to inspect the element and low and behold the allowTransparency attribute exists, but the contents is set to blank. Even if I manually change this value back to "true" in the tool, it is immediately cleared out and ignored.

Initially I thought this was an issue directly in my jsp page with conflicting styles etc, so I tried it in the w3schools "tryit" editor and exactly the same thing happens with the following code:

```
<body>
<iframe src="..." width="800" height="400" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true">
</body>
</html>
```

Where src is the source of my test page. I am running ie 9. Is there any reason why the allowtransparency field is being cleared / ignored?

Cheers,

Jason.

Comment: Well some offtopic but why do you use frames? You could also load any code dynamic with `AJAX` and `DOM` or also with a framework like jQuery.

Comment: Agreed, but it doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: That is why I wrote a comment and no answer ;-)

Comment: ok, well yes, I agree with you, but I'd like to know all the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit more investigation I found the answer to my question. Apparently IE 9 No longer supports the allowTransparency attribute. As can be found in the following link:

http://help.dottoro.com/lhjvodln.php

I can't however find anything official on MSDN, but meh, I'm pretty sure the information in the link is correct and explains what is happening.